# jQuery not recognizing click for li item on second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working to make a couple buttons to change the theme of a website on click. They work on the main page, but when I tried to move them to the second page, they don't work anymore. The click isn't even being recognized at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#warm", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    $(b).addClass('color-red');
    $(li).addClass('color-red #pages li');
    $(h1).addClass('color-red h1');
    $('#pages').addClass('color-red #pages');
  });}
```

Here is the html that goes with it

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <ul id="colors">
    <li id="warm">
      Warm
    </li>
    <li id="cool">
      Cool
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The cool function is exactly the same as the warm, except it uses removeClass instead of addClass.

Comment: Are you ensuring that the function itself is being referenced / registered (as well as jQuery)? Do you have any Javascript / jQuery-related errors within the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser? You also appear to have some syntax issues (e.g. missing a closing `)` within your `document.ready()` function, no indications of where your selectors are coming from `$(b)`, `$(li)`, etc.)

Comment: is there a reference to jquery in this second page ? is it bore this code?

Comment: `$(b)` isn't valid syntax unless `b` is a variable. You probably meant `$('b')`. Same for the rest.

Comment: Is the HTML code of the second page generated with javascript (async loading, DOM Element creation,...) ?

Comment: please use `$('#warm').click(function(e){});` instead of `.on("click",....`

Comment: @Pero i dont think using .click vs .on('click', func(e)) would make a difference, if you read the api you will see that .click is short hand for .on('click') in fact to speed up your jquery you want to use on instead of .click.  .click has to make another call to convert it to .on('click') losing precious ms.  what he doenst want to do is use $(document).on('click') as that is super expensive.

Comment: @JDE thank you , i'm used to the short version. Thought "on" could be the old way.

@SpencerMcFadden are css classes like `#pages` valid?

Comment: @Pero No problem.  I almost always use the .on compared to the short hand versions.  It keeps my events looking uniform so if im doing a $(document).on for future eventing or a $(li).on("click", dataobj, func) my code consistently stays the same.  Also "#pages" may not be html valid, but it does add the "#pages" class if you test it out (in chrome at least);

Comment: @JDE seems like a good structure ;)
**Back to topic:** what do you mean by "move to the second page"? Does the jQuery-Code get loaded on every page?

Comment: @ Pero #pages is valid, it's an id used in my css. The jQuery code does get loaded on every page. The click event is there when I check, but it is not being recognized

Comment: b is also a variable for the body. 

`var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#warm", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    $(b).addClass('color-red');
    $(li).addClass('color-red #pages li');
    $(h1).addClass('color-red h1');
    $('#pages').addClass('color-red #pages');
  });}
```

WOAHHH Back it up partner.  First you dont ever want to bind to document, UNLESS you are creating future events.  Since you are using the id selector, you should only have 1 of those on the page, which you can rebind if you rebind that particular id to the page.  You dont want to blind to the document because it is quite heavy or something.  jquery has to parse the entire DOM everytime there is an html change to check if you added another "#warm" (in your example) to see if it needs to create another event binding to that element.

So first off your code should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#warm").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    $(b).addClass('color-red');
    $(li).addClass('color-red #pages li');
    $(h1).addClass('color-red h1');
    $('#pages').addClass('color-red #pages');
  });}
```

now time for some clarification, what do you mean you "move them to the second page"?  What code in there says you are moving them ? What is the second page?

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `$('b')` etc unless they're variables?